# Как настроить eslint для namespace в es5

Tags: namespace, eslint

Использую es5, код поделен на модули IIFE.
Между модулями передаю переменные в объектах типа:

```
var MySite = MySite || {};
MySite.Module1 = MySite.Module1 || {};
MySite.Module1.var1 = MySite.Module1.var1 || {};
```

Потом в самих модулях IIFE обращаюсь к этим объектам:

```
var varFromModule1 = MySite.Module1.var1;
```

Вот на эту последнюю строчку eslint, естественно, ругается:

```
"MySite" is not defined. (no-undef)
```

Эту настройку в eslint отключать не хочется по понятным причинам.
Есть какие-то решения, чтобы эти namespace не подсвечивались как ошибки ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там в конфиге есть раздел `globals` - в нём нужно прописать все существующие глобальные переменные. Подробнее: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals